# Sharing an AVL Tree Between Several Classes

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree implemented.

So, let's say I have two classes, one that parses through an XML of different types of Apples and another the parses through different types of Oranges.

If I instantiate the tree in the `Apples_Parser.cs` class, how can I use that same tree to load the different types of oranges which would be loaded into the tree in from the `Oranges_Parser.cs` class?

This isn't homework, I've just generalized the question to make it easier (no code to provide yet, I'm at a loss on where to begin)

Comment: What does the parser interface look like in `Apples_Parser` and `Orange_Parser`?

Comment: Do you want the same tree to contain both apples and oranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper class, that contains an instance of the tree, then use that instance in both `Apple_parser` and `Oranges_Parser` classes.

```
public static class AvlFactory
{
     private static AvlTree _avlTree;
     public static AvlTree AvlTree{ get {return _avlTree; }}
     public static void InitializeTree()
     {
         _avlTree = new AvlTree();
     }
}
```

Then in `Apples_Praser` or `Oranges_Praser` class:

```
if(AvlFactory.AvlTree == null)
{
    AvlFactory.InitializeTree();
}
//Codes to load data to the tree
```

In this way whichever parser that used first will instantiate the tree and the other just adds data to it.

Comment: Thank you, I think that is what I need.